# How to return a single model in Laravel from a hasManyThrough eloquent relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, relationship

I have the following table structure:

```
tickets

 - id

assignments

 - id
 - ticket_id
 - staff_id
 - role
 - isAssigned

staff

 - id
 - username
```

I have created a [`hasManyThrough`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) relationship on the `tickets` model which successfully returns all the `staff` associated with the `ticket` through the `assignments` table.

```
public function staff()
{
  return $this->hasManyThrough(Staff::class, Assignment::class);
}
```

The `assignments` table can hold 1 or more records for a `ticket` for the same `role` where the `isAssigned` flag specifies whether the `staff` association is active. As such only 1 record for a given `role` will ever have `isAssigned = 1`

I make use of [`query scopes`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#local-scopes) to limit the results returned by the `hasManyThrough` relationship, for example:

```
public function scopeWithAssignedEngineer($builder)
{
  $filter = function ($staff) {
    $staff->where([['isAssigned', 1], ['role', 'engineer']]);
  };
  return $builder->whereHas('staff', $filter)->with(['staff' => $filter]);
}
```

So if I call `Ticket::withAssignedEngineer()->where('id', 123)->get();` I get my ticket along with the assigned engineer however, the engineer is a collection rather than an item.

```
ticket: {
  id: 123,
  assigned_engineer: [
    {
      ...
    }
  ]
}
```

When using the response I can call `$ticket->assignedEngineer->first()` to get the engineer, however, I would prefer to not have to call first on every such collection.

So;

#### Question 1

Is my `hasManyThrough` relationship correct, or have I overcomplicated things here?

#### Question 2

Is there something I can on or to my `scopes` which work on `hasMany` relationships that will only return a single `item` inside the `collection` so that I do not have to call `->first()` each time?

Comment: Is the relationship called `staff` or `assignedEngineer`? Or are they different relationships?

Comment: There can be more than one assigned engineers? Please share your staff definition in your model.

Comment: There's no way for `hasManyThrough` to return 1 item only. You can use `->take(1)` but it will still be wrapped in a collection. You're probably better off making a `belongsToMany` to connect `tickets` to `staff` and the other way around. And use `assignments` as a pivot table.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir - The `hasManyThrough` relationship is called `staff` which returns all `staff` associted with the `ticket`.  The scopeWithAssignedEngineer `scope` uses the `staff` relationship but filters it further.

Comment: Is `assignedEngineer` in the response just the `staff` result? Or do you filter by `role`?

Comment: The `assignedEngineer` in the response is the result of calling the `withAssignedEngineer` scope which filters the `staff` `hasManyThrough` relationship by `role`.  I've added the relationship to my question for clarity.

Comment: @devk - Using a pivot table still results in a collection.

Comment: I'm aware of that, unfortunately there's no relationship that would make what you want possible. If you're feeling adventurous, you could try [this](https://packalyst.com/packages/package/riesjart/relaquent) package.

Comment: Can you add the whole `scopeWithAssignedEngineer()` method?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir - The `scopeWithAssignedEngineer` in my question is all of it.

Comment: Where's the `role` filtering happening?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir - Apologies, I didn't notice I hadn't added that to the `scopeWithAssignedEngineer`.  Added it now.

Answer (score 0):

Not the most elegant solution, but it works.

Change `assignedEngineer` to `assignedEngineers` and add an [accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) to the `Ticket` model:

```
public function getAssignedEngineerAttribute() {
    return $this->assignedEngineers->first();
}
```

Then you can get a single `Staff` model like this:

```
$ticket->assignedEngineer
```

If you're returning a JSON response, add this to `Ticket`:

```
protected $appends = ['assignedEngineer'];
```